# How to predict more than one value for each sequence in Keras? LSTM Layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**First of all, if the question has no sense sorry, please correct me**.

So... I have this Sequential model.

```
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM( 524 , input_shape = (sequeces, size) , return_sequences = True ))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(LSTM( 256, return_sequences = True ))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(LSTM( 128 ))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add( Dense( 32, activation='relu') )
    model.add( Dropout(0.2))

    model.add( Dense( num_y_signals , activation='softmax') )

    model.compile(
        loss      = 'categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam( lr = 0.001 , decay=1e-6 ),
        metrics   = ['accuracy']
    )
```

This is the shape for 1 sequence

**x_shape = (1, 24, 252)**

**y_shape = (1, 24, 2)**

But i get this error when i fit the model

**ValueError: A target array with shape (1, 24, 2) was passed for an output of shape (None, 2) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.**

my suposition that the last layer output shape has to be modified some way... but i have no idea how

**Extra Information:**

How i fit the model

```
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs = 200, verbose = 1 )
```

X and Y data Example

```
[[[4.73778108e-01 7.81242029e-04 4.30468356e-01 ... 4.00000000e+00
   6.00000000e+00 7.00000000e+00]
  [4.81112145e-01 5.23199660e-05 4.17750945e-01 ... 4.00000000e+00
   6.00000000e+00 6.00000000e+00]
  [4.86817225e-01 2.95250670e-05 4.19276930e-01 ... 4.00000000e+00
   6.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00]
  ...
  [4.81959516e-01 1.60327432e-04 4.32056797e-01 ... 4.00000000e+00
   5.00000000e+00 9.00000000e+00]
  [4.83579230e-01 6.00398605e-04 4.29610771e-01 ... 4.00000000e+00
   5.00000000e+00 8.00000000e+00]
  [4.81143261e-01 5.71228103e-04 4.39182101e-01 ... 4.00000000e+00
   5.00000000e+00 7.00000000e+00]]]

[[[1 0]
  [0 1]
  [0 1]
  [0 0]
  [0 0]
  [1 0]
  [1 0]
  [1 0]
  [1 0]
  [0 1]
  [0 0]
  [0 0]
  [0 1]
  [0 1]
  [0 1]
  [0 0]
  [1 0]
  [0 1]
  [0 1]
  [1 0]
  [1 0]
  [1 0]
  [1 0]
  [1 0]]]
```

Comment: I supose i could do that, but why i should do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set return_sequence = True in the last LSTM cell

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM( 524 , input_shape = (24, 252) , return_sequences = True ))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM( 256, return_sequences = True ))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM( 128, return_sequences = True  )) # <================
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add( Dense( 32, activation='relu') )
model.add( Dropout(0.2))

model.add( Dense( 2 , activation='softmax') )

model.compile(
    loss      = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam( lr = 0.001 , decay=1e-6 ),
    metrics   = ['accuracy']
)
```

the rest seems ok

in this way your last layer can predict a target of shapes (None, 24, 2)